# Pinch Zoom And Scroll multitouch source code

Tags: android, licensing, pinchzoom

Today , i have covered a serious problem . I have just created a apps including this library https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom
source code used completely. Now i wanna upload it into Google Pay but i am confuse that will this license any effect in future in my apps https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom/blob/master/LICENSE

Do i needs first purchase it ? do here any other ways so i will use this freely.
please expert help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can upload this without any risk...don't worry bro...because i have used this demo..and upload app in google play.

Answer (score 1):

this software uses the [MIT license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) which means that you can use and resell (as a part of your developed software) it completly free
However, you need to include the above linked license text into your applications source code (e.g. file xy.js contains content licensed under MIT, so you need to add (or leave) the license and copyright information there)

Comment: if i will not include license link .there is any risk .

Comment: edited my answer above... sorry for the confusion. You don't need to include the MIT license into your applications license